# adding elements of variable number of arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need a function where I can input an array with a variable number of subarrays.
The function should add the numbers of the subarrays of each position.
this is an example input array with three subarrays (could also be two or more):

```
   [ [ [ 12 ], [ 8 ], [ 2 ], [ 9 ], [ 2 ], [ 2 ] ],
      [ [ 3 ], [ 4 ], [ 2 ], [ 3 ], [ 2 ], [ 2 ] ],
      [ [ 6 ], [ 2 ], [ 2 ], [ 3 ], [ 2 ], [ 2 ] ] ]
```

the function should output:

```
[ 21, 14, 6, 15, 6, 6 ]
```

Comment: and what did you try so far?

Comment: 'function addarrays() {
    var outputarray = [];
    asyncLoop2(arguments.length-2,
        function(loop){
           outputarray = addtwoarrays(arguments[i],arguments[i+1]);
            loop.next();
        }, function(){return outputarray  ;});
}'  "function addarrays() {
    var outputarray = [];
    asyncLoop2(arguments.length-2,
        function(loop){
           outputarray = addtwoarrays(arguments[i],arguments[i+1]);
            loop.next();
        }, function(){return outputarray  ;});
}"   [here](http://moourl.com/ai24t) is the async loop funtion I call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = [ [ [ 12 ], [ 8 ], [ 2 ], [ 9 ], [ 2 ], [ 2 ] ],
      [ [ 3 ], [ 4 ], [ 2 ], [ 3 ], [ 2 ], [ 2 ] ],
      [ [ 6 ], [ 2 ], [ 2 ], [ 3 ], [ 2 ], [ 2 ] ] ];

function adder(inputData) {
    var resultArray = new Array(inputData[0].length);
    for (var i = 0, len = inputData.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        for (var j = 0, len1 = inputData[i].length; j < len1; j += 1) {
            if (resultArray[j]) {
                resultArray[j] += parseInt(inputData[i][j]);
            } else {
                resultArray[j] = parseInt(inputData[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return resultArray;
}

console.log(adder(data));
```

**Result**

```
[ 21, 14, 6, 15, 6, 6 ]
```

Comment: fast answer wow, that would have taken me a week or so, thx man

Answer (score 1):

```
function sumSubArrays(array) {
    if (array.length == 0) {
        return new Array();
    }
    var resultLength = array[0].length;
    var result = new Array(resultLength);
    for (var i = 0; i < resultLength; i++) {
        var tmp = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            tmp += array[j][i][0];
        }
        result[i] = tmp;
    }
    return result;
}
```